# How can I find fields with the same values in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find matches with the same match_id but I am unable to solution using mongoose . Any help would be appreciated , thank you. My match_id is type String and I want to check for duplicate matches that are being created .
Match Schema :

```
const MatchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  match_id: {
    type: String,
  },
  player1Id: {
    type: String,
  },
  player2Id: {
    type: String,
  },
  player1VideoId: {
    type: String,
    default: "blank",
  },
  player2VideoId: {
    type: String,
    default: "blank",
  },
  player1Score: {
    type: Object,
    default:{'noOne':0}
  },
  player2Score: {
    type: Object,
    default:{'noOne':0}
  },
  isWinner:{
    type:String,
  },
  round:{
    type: Number,
  },
  tournamentCategory:{
    type:String,
  },
  tournamentId:{
    type:ObjectID,
  },
  player1Details: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Contestant",
  },
  player2Details: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Contestant",
  },
});
```

Comment: `MatchSchema.find({match_id: "XXXXX"})` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `$group` for grouping data based on `match_id` , and select fields with count > 1, like this

```
let x = await Model.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id : "$match_id",
            result : {$push:"$$ROOT"},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
         { "$match": { "count": { "$gte": 2 } } }  

])
```